# I have a set of queries in rdd that I want to execute seqenetially

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**code**

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///C:/Naresh/data/ghgh").map(f =>"select count (*) from"+ " "+f.replace(",",".")).map(f => f.replace(".false",""))
rdd.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are trying to do. It seems a bit vague as you added SQL statements & map in the same statement

Comment: Hi there, can you provide an example of input/output data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run multiple operators sequentially,the best way for doing this ,is by creating multiple operators at the same `SparkContext` and then apply one another.
Especially for SQL queries,you should definitely try converting RDD to dataframes,it's much easier to apply such operators on Spark dataframes.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///C:/Naresh/data/ghgh").map(_.split(",")).toDF()
val query = spark.sql("SELECT count (*) FROM table")
query.map(f => f.replace("false"," "))
```

e.g. I am not sure,but i think this is the only way,since SQL queries only apply on structure data,but,as i said i am not completely sure for that.